# The android virtual machine it suddenly disappears and doesn't report any errors

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react-native

After I edit Podfile I have to run **"cd ios && pod install"**

I wonder if I edit AndroidMainfest.xml and build.gradle in android do I have to run something like **pod install**?

Because currently my application when running the command on the android virtual machine it suddenly disappears and doesn't report any errors, but on the ios virtual machine it still works normally

Does anyone have an answer to this problem? please let me know
Thank you so much guys <3

Answer (score 1):

When installing new packages to your react native app or edit your Podfile, you wanna run pod install. This is the only time you should run pod install. Anytime else makes no sense and changes nothing. Pod install doesn't effect android. Whenever you change code inside your /android folder, you need to run react-native run-android for the changes to be applied. Whenever you change code inside your /ios folder, you need to run react-native run-ios for the changes to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Yep you have to do that on android when making changes to the native android files or installing packages that rely on them, although the emulator disappearing shouldn't be related to this

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```